# Validate URL jQuery

Tags: jquery, razor

Can't seem to get this sorted...

I'm trying to validate 2 inputs to verify that both are valid URLs. I.e. http://www.somename.com.

It's breaking my application though (ASP.NET RAZOR). Says some Parsing issue and points to the domainPattern var as the culprit.

Any guesses?

```
// validate domain url
var url = $('.sb-terms-url, .sb-privacy-url').val();
var domainPattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
if (!domainPattern.test(url)) {
    $('.sb-privacyalert').fadeIn(600);

}
else {
    $(this).trigger('reveal:close');

    $('.terms-link').attr('href', $('.sb-terms-url').val());
    $('.privacy-link').attr('href', $('.sb-privacy-url').val());

    $('.sb-privacyalert').fadeOut(300);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this line is your issue:

```
var domainPattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

because it contains the `@` symbol which razor picks up and tries to parse as razor syntax.  You can escape that character though using it twice in a row like `@@` in which case razor spits out just `@` which will then work with your regular expression.

This should work:

```
var domainPattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@@!\-\/]))?/;
```

Comment: I'm not a regex guy, but can you confirm that there is only 1 `@` symbol after the razor view engine runs?

Comment: Yeah...you and me both. Page is rendering the var correctly. Only 1 @

Comment: All is well. I had some classes mixed up. Thanks for your help!